# Nginx locations, try_files and headers issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, puma

So I've replaced Passenger with Puma for a Rails app, and i just noticed that i now have issues with the cdn assets, they now give CORS errors.

Back when i was using Passenger i had the following configs for Nginx:

```
server {

  server_name mysite.com;
  root /var/www/mysite.com/public;

  client_max_body_size 4000M;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;

  location ~* ^/cdn/ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires 364d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    break;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  #the rest of the certbot ssl stuff

}
```

I then changed the configs to this to make it work with Puma and unix sockets:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///var/www/mysite.com/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}
server {

  server_name mysite.com;
  root /var/www/mysite.com/public;

  client_max_body_size 4000M;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location ~* ^/cdn/ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires 364d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    break;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  #ssl stuff

  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://puma;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

This works fine but then i noticed that the cdn urls were giving 404, so i updated the cdn location to this (i added `try_files $uri @app;`):

```
  location ~* ^/cdn/ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires 364d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri @app;
    break;
  }
```

This now works but i get CORS errors so it seems the headers are not getting set.

My guess is the `try_files` ignores what was set before it is called, so i tried setting the proxy header for access control inside the `location @app` (by adding `proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;`) but i still get the errors.

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: What is the matter of using regex locations like `location ~* ^/cdn/ { ... }` instead of prefix `location /cdn/ { ... }` ones? Do you understand the performance impact? What does it mean _i tried setting the proxy header for access control inside the `location @app`_? How do you tried it? Show what you've tried in your answer, please.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I've added the requested info, basically i tried adding `proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` but that didnt do any good. thanks for the location tip, i'll update those.

Comment: That way you've added CORS header to the request going to the upstream, not to the response received by the client. To add header to the response use the same `add_header` as you used in your static location. If the same header with the wrong value is received from the upstream, remove it explicitly before adding a new one with the [`proxy_hide_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) directive.

Comment: @IvanShatsky ok thanks i will try that, but this will add the header to every request right? how do i limit it to the specific /cdn/ location along with the `expires`? I don't want the entire site to be cached and allow CORS, just the assets returned by the `/cdn/` location, but i fail to understand how that is done now that there is an upstream.

Comment: I've already seen this (kind of strange) nginx configuration for Rails and Puma several times before. Just out of curiosity, where is it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sense in trying to add the response headers with the `proxy_set_header` directive - it is designed for adding/changing headers for the request that will be sent to the upstream. To add the response headers, no matter is it a static or a proxied location, use the `add_header` one. To add headers conditionally, lets say depending on a request URI, you can use the [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block(s):

```
map $uri $expires {
    ~^/cdn/  1y;
    default  off;
}
map $uri $cache_control {
    ~^/cdn/  public;
    # default will be an empty value
}
map $uri $allow_origin {
    ~^/cdn/  *;
    # default will be an empty value
}
```

However in terms of performance, since all the `map`-derived variables are evaluated only once per request, matching regex pattern only once can be slightly more performant:

```
map $cache $expires {
    1        1y;
    default  off;
}
map $cache $cache_control {
    1        public;
}
map $cache $allow_origin {
    1        *;
}
map $uri $cache {
    ~^/cdn/  1;
}
```

Next, in your `@app` location you can use the following:

```
location @app {
    proxy_pass http://puma;

    expires $expires;
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $allow_origin;

    # ... proxy_set_... and other upstream setup here
}
```

If evaluated variable used in an `add_header` directive will be empty, nginx won't add a header with an empty value - instead it won't add such a header at all.

---

A few notes about your current config:

- Using those kind of regex locations like `location ~ ^/cdn/ { ... }` or `location ~ ^/assets/ { ... }` in favor of prefix locations `location /cdn/ { ... }` or `location /assets/ { ... }` makes no sense and only a performance impact (due to the PCRE library is involved when it isn't nessesary).
- That [`break`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break) directive at the end of static locations does nothing since there are no any directives from the rewrite module there which execution should be stopped.